# Does "volatile" guarantee anything at all in portable C code for multi-core systems?

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, volatile, portability

After looking at a [bunch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484980/why-is-volatile-not-considered-useful-in-multithreaded-c-or-c-programming?noredirect=1&lq=1) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78172/using-c-pthreads-do-shared-variables-need-to-be-volatile) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837699/are-mutex-lock-functions-sufficient-without-volatile?noredirect=1&lq=1) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449562/when-would-you-need-a-volatile-pointer) [and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478397/atomic-swap-in-gnu-c/2478520#2478520) [their](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44243426/706054) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2485733/706054), I get the impression that **there is no widespread agreement on what the "volatile" keyword in C means exactly.**

Even the standard itself does not seem to be clear enough for everyone to agree on [what it means](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1956.htm).

Among other problems:

1. It seems to provide different guarantees depending on your hardware and depending on your compiler.
2. It affects compiler optimizations but not hardware optimizations, so on an advanced processor that does its own run-time optimizations, it is not even clear whether the compiler *can* prevent whatever optimization you want to prevent. (Some compilers do generate instructions to prevent some hardware optimizations on some systems, but this does not appear to be standardized in any way.)

To summarize the problem, it appears (after reading a lot) that "volatile" guarantees something like: *The value will be read/written not just from/to a register, but at least to the core's L1 cache, in the same order that the reads/writes appear in the code.* But this seems useless, since reading/writing from/to a register is already sufficient within the same thread, while coordinating with L1 cache doesn't guarantee anything further regarding coordination with other threads.  I can't imagine when it could ever be important to sync just with L1 cache.

**USE 1**

The only widely-agreed-upon use of volatile seems to be for old or embedded systems where certain memory locations are hardware-mapped to I/O functions, like a bit in memory that controls (directly, in the hardware) a light, or a bit in memory that tells you whether a keyboard key is down or not (because it is connected by the hardware directly to the key).

It seems that **"use 1" does not occur in portable code whose targets include multi-core systems.**

**USE 2**

Not too different from "use 1" is memory that could be read or written at any time by an interrupt handler (which might control a light or store info from a key).  But already for this we have the problem that depending on the system, the interrupt handler [might run on](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33955582/706054) [a different core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25153972/706054) with [its own memory cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/954069/706054), and "volatile" does not guarantee cache coherency on all systems.

So **"use 2" seems to be beyond what "volatile" can deliver.**

**USE 3**

The only other undisputed use I see is to prevent mis-optimization of accesses via different variables pointing to the same memory that the compiler doesn't realize is the same memory.  But this is probably only undisputed because people aren't talking about it -- I only saw one mention of it.  And I thought the C standard already recognized that "different" pointers (like different args to a function) might point to the same item or nearby items, and already specified that the compiler must produce code that works even in such cases.  However, I couldn't quickly find this topic in the latest (500 page!) standard.

So **"use 3" maybe doesn't exist** at all?

*Hence my question:*

**Does "volatile" guarantee anything at all in portable C code for multi-core systems?**

---

### EDIT -- update

After browsing the [latest standard](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf), it is looking like the answer is at least a *very* limited yes:

1.  The standard repeatedly specifies special treatment for the specific type "volatile sig_atomic_t".  However the standard also says that use of the signal function in a multi-threaded program results in undefined behavior.  So this use case seems limited to communication between a single-threaded program and its signal handler.

2. The standard also specifies a clear meaning for "volatile" in relation to setjmp/longjmp. (Example code where it matters is given in other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393443/setjmp-longjmp-and-local-variables) and [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996825/why-volatile-works-for-setjmp-longjmp).)

So the more precise question becomes:

**Does "volatile" guarantee anything at all in portable C code for multi-core systems, apart from (1) allowing a single-threaded program to receive information from its signal handler, or (2) allowing setjmp code to see variables modified between setjmp and longjmp?**

*This is still a yes/no question.*

*If "yes", it would be great if you could show an example of bug-free portable code which becomes buggy if "volatile" is omitted.  If "no", then I suppose a compiler is free to ignore "volatile" outside of these two very specific cases, for multi-core targets.*

Comment: Signals exist in portable C; what about a global variable that's updated by a signal handler?  This would need to be `volatile` to inform the program that it may change asynchronously.

Comment: @NateEldredge Global, while volatile alone, is not good enough. It needs to be atomic as well.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Yes, of course.  But the question at hand is about `volatile` specifically, which I believe is necessary.

Comment: "_while coordinating with L1 cache doesn't guarantee anything further regarding coordination with other threads_" Where is "coordinating with L1 cache" not sufficient to communicate w/ other threads?

Comment: @curiousguy: Are you saying that "volatile" provides cache coherency? Or that cache coherency is not a problem?

Comment: Maybe relevant, [C++ proposal to deprecate volatile](http://wg21.link/P1152), the proposal addresses many of the concerns you raise here , and perhaps its outcome will be influential to the C committee

Comment: @curiousguy: Another question relevant to that topic: [c-volatile-variables-and-cache-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872175/c-volatile-variables-and-cache-memory)

Comment: @Matt I'm saying neither of these things.

Comment: @M.M "C++ proposal to deprecate volatile" Internal links are broken: `<a href="wg21.link/P1152R0#over">`. Sad!

Comment: @curiousguy: It seems you can get to the info of the broken links via the link to [P1152R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1152r0.html) in the endnotes.

Comment: @M.M "C++ proposal to deprecate volatile" is really a proposal to make volatile great again by removing the nonsensical copy pasta of const qualification into volatile qualification and make all possible uses of volatile in the type system relevant for MMIO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To summarize the problem, it appears (after reading a lot) that
>   "volatile" guarantees something like: The value will be read/written
>   not just from/to a register, but **at least to the core's L1 cache, in
>   the same order that the reads/writes appear in the code**.

No, **it absolutely does not**. And that makes volatile almost useless for the purpose of MT safe code.

If it did, then volatile would be quite good for variables shared by multiple thread as ordering the events in the L1 cache is all you need to do in typical CPU (that is either multi-core or multi-CPU on motherboard) capable of cooperating in a way that makes a normal implementation of either C/C++ or Java multithreading possible with typical expected costs (that is, not a huge cost on most atomic or non-contented mutex operations).

But volatile does *not* provide any guaranteed ordering (or "memory visibility") in the cache either in theory or in practice.

(Note: the following is based on sound interpretation of the standard documents, the standard's intent, historical practice, and a deep understand of the expectations of compiler writers. This approach based on history, actual practices, and expectations and understanding of real persons in the real world, which is much stronger and more reliable than parsing the words of a document that is not known to be stellar specification writing and which has been revised many times.)

In practice, **volatile does guarantees ptrace-ability that is the ability to use debug information for the running program, at any level of optimization**, and the fact the debug information makes sense for these volatile objects:

- you may use `ptrace` (a ptrace-like mechanism) to set meaningful break points at the sequence points after operations involving volatile objects: you can really break at exactly these points (note that this works only if you are willing to set many break points as any C/C++ statement may be compiled to many different assembly start and end points, as in a massively unrolled loop);
- while a thread of execution of stopped, you may read the value of all volatile objects, as they have their canonical representation (following the ABI for their respective type); a non volatile local variable could have an atypical representation, f.ex. a shifted representation: a variable used for indexing an array might be multiplied by the size of individual objects, for easier indexing; or it might be replaced by a pointer to an array element (as long as all uses of the variable as similarly converted) (think changing dx to du in an integral);
- you can also modify those objects (as long as the memory mappings allow that, as volatile object with static lifetime that are const qualified might be in a memory range mapped read only).

Volatile guarantee in practice a little more than the strict ptrace interpretation: it also guarantees that volatile automatic variables have an address on the stack, as they aren't allocated to a register, a register allocation which would make ptrace manipulations more delicate (compiler can output debug information to explain how variables are allocated to registers, but reading and changing register state is slightly more involved than accessing memory addresses).

Note that full program debug-ability, that is considering all variables volatile at least at sequence points, is provided by the "zero optimization" mode of the compiler, a mode which still performs trivial optimizations like arithmetic simplifications (there is usually no guaranteed no optimization at all mode). But volatile is stronger than non optimization: `x-x` can be simplified for a non volatile integer `x` but not of a volatile object.

So **volatile means guaranteed to be compiled as is**, like the translation from source to binary/assembly by the compiler of a system call isn't a reinterpretation, changed, or optimized in any way by a compiler. Note that library calls may or may not be system calls. Many official system functions are actually library function that offer a thin layer of interposition and generally defer to the kernel at the end. (In particular `getpid` doesn't need to go to the kernel and could well read a memory location provided by the OS containing the information.)

**Volatile interactions are interactions with the outside world of the real machine**, which must follow the "abstract machine". They aren't internal interactions of program parts with other program parts. The compiler can only reason about what it knows, that is the internal program parts.

The code generation for a volatile access should follow the most natural interaction with that memory location: it should be unsurprising. That means that *some volatile accesses are expected to be atomic*: if the natural way to read or write the representation of a `long` on the architecture is atomic, then it's expected that a read or write of a `volatile long` will be atomic, *as the compiler should not generate silly inefficient code to access volatile objects byte by byte, for example*.

You should be able to determine that by knowing the architecture. You don't have to know anything about the compiler, as **volatile means that the compiler should be transparent**.

But volatile does no more than force the emission of expected assembly for the least optimized for particular cases to do a memory operation: volatile semantics means general case semantic.

The general case is what the compiler does when it doesn't have any information about a construct: f.ex. calling a virtual function on an lvalue via dynamic dispatch is a general case, making a direct call to the overrider after determining at compile time the type of the object designated by the expression is a particular case. The compiler always have a general case handling of all constructs, and it follows the ABI.

Volatile does nothing special to synchronize threads or provide "memory visibility": **volatile only provides guarantees at the abstract level** seen from inside a thread executing or stopped, that is **the inside of a CPU core**:

- volatile says nothing about which memory operations reach main RAM (you may set specific memory caching types with assembly instructions or system calls to obtain these guarantees);
- **volatile doesn't provide any guarantee about when memory operations will be committed to any level of cache (not even L1)**.

Only the second point means volatile is not useful in most inter threads communication problems; the first point is essentially irrelevant in any programming problem that doesn't involve communication with hardware components outside the CPU(s) but still on the memory bus.

The property of volatile providing guaranteed behavior from the point of the view of the core running the thread means that asynchronous signals delivered to that thread, which are run from the point of view of the execution ordering of that thread, see operations in source code order.

Unless you plan to send signals to your threads (an extremely useful approach to consolidation of information about currently running threads with no previously agreed point of stopping), volatile is not for you.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, there's historically been various hiccups regarding different intepretations of the meaning of `volatile` access and similar. See this study: [Volatiles Are Miscompiled, and What to Do about It](https://www.cs.utah.edu/%7Eregehr/papers/emsoft08-preprint.pdf).

Apart from the various issues mentioned in that study, the behavior of `volatile` is portable, save for one aspect of them: when they act as  *memory barriers*. A memory barrier is some mechanism which is there to prevent concurrent unsequenced execution of your code. Using `volatile` as a memory barrier is certainly not portable.

Whether the C language guarantees memory behavior or not from `volatile` is apparently arguable, though personally I think the language is clear. First we have the formal definition of side effects, C17 5.1.2.3:

> Accessing a `volatile` object, modifying an object, modifying a file, or calling a function that does any of those operations are all *side effects*, which are changes in the state of the execution environment.

The standard defines the term sequencing, as a way of determining order of evaluation (execution). The definition is formal and cumbersome:

> *Sequenced before* is an asymmetric, transitive, pair-wise relation between evaluations
> executed by a single thread, which induces a partial order among those evaluations.
> Given any two evaluations A and B, if A is sequenced before B, then the execution of A
> shall precede the execution of B. (Conversely, if A is sequenced before B, then B is
> *sequenced after* A.) If A is not sequenced before or after B, then A and B are
> *unsequenced*. Evaluations A and B are *indeterminately sequenced* when A is sequenced
> either before or after B, but it is unspecified which.13) The presence of a *sequence point*
> between the evaluation of expressions A and B implies that every value computation and
> side effect associated with A is sequenced before every value computation and side effect
> associated with B. (A summary of the sequence points is given in annex C.)

The TL;DR of the above is basically that in case we have an expression `A` which contains side-effects, it must be done executing before another expression `B`, in case `B` is sequenced after `A`.

Optimizations of C code are made possible through this part:

> In the abstract machine, all expressions are evaluated as specified by the semantics. An actual
> implementation need not evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that its value is not used and that no needed side effects are produced (including any caused by calling a function or accessing a
> volatile object).

This means that the program may evaluate (execute) expressions in the order that the standard mandates elsewhere (order of evaluation etc). But it need not evaluate (execute) a value if it can deduce that it is not used. For example, the operation `0 * x` doesn't need to evaluate `x` and simply replace the expression with `0`.

*Unless* accessing a variable is a side-effect. Meaning that in case `x` is `volatile`, it *must* evaluate (execute) `0 * x` even though the result will always be 0. Optimization is not allowed.

Furthermore, the standard speaks of observable behavior:

> The least requirements on a conforming implementation are:
>
> - Accesses to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine.
>   /--/
>   This is the *observable behavior* of the program.

Given all of the above, a conforming implementation (compiler + underlying system) may not execute the access of `volatile` objects in an unsequenced order, in case the semantics of the written C source says otherwise.

This means that in this example

```
volatile int x;
volatile int y;
z = x;
z = y;
```

Both assignment expressions *must* be evaluated and `z = x;` *must* be evaluated before `z = y;`. A multi-processor implementation that outsource these two operations to two different unsequenced cores is not conforming!

The dilemma is that compilers can't do much about things like pre-fetch caching and instruction pipelining etc, particularly not when running on top of an OS. And so compilers hand that problem over to the programmers, telling them that memory barriers is now the programmer's responsibility. While the C standard clearly states that the problem needs to be solved by the compiler.

The compiler doesn't necessarily care to solve the problem though, and so `volatile` for the sake of acting as a memory barrier is non-portable. It has become a quality of implementation issue.

Comment: @curiousguy Doesn't matter.

Comment: @curiousguy Doesn't matter, as long as it is some sort of integer type with or without qualifiers.

Comment: If it's a simple non volatile integer, why would redundant writes to `z` be really executed? (like `z = x;
z = y;`) The value is going to be erased in the next statement.

Comment: @curiousguy Because the _reads_ to the volatile variables have to be executed no matter, in the specified sequence.

Comment: Then is `z` really assigned twice? How do you know that "reads are executed"?

Comment: @curiousguy The compiler doesn't need to write to `z` twice if it isn't `volatile`. It does however have to read `x` and then read `y`. The presence of a `volatile` variable in an evaluated expression is enough to enforce a read. A compiler generating such code would be compliant. However in practice, I suspect that most compilers do write to `z` twice since that's the most convenient way of generating the machine code.

Comment: The memory-fence aspect seems to only apply to volatile variables (it is not a general memory fence), and even there the language used in the standard is not clear about whether it applies between *different* volatile variables. In the part you quote last, for example, "volatile objects" could be read either as "all volatile objects considered together" (as you seem to be reading it) or as "individual volatile objects" (like you would assume in a sentence like "Court cases are evaluated strictly according to the law."). In the latter case, your example with `x` and `y` could be reordered.

Comment: Nice article by the way (referenced in your first paragraph), although it is a bit discouraging!

Comment: @Matt Sequence points in relation to volatile access is what matters. If we have a volatile access in `z = x;` then no other volatile access can be sequenced before that, since there is a sequence point at `;`. Take the real-world scenario where a volatile status register _must_ be read before a volatile data register. A compiler that would re-organize the individual side-effects in other ways than the sequence points demand, would be a utterly broken compiler.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, the motivation for why it *should* work this way is clear. (And the document you link to points out that major compilers *are* utterly broken regarding volatile!) My point was just that the wording of the standard is ambiguous regarding whether this is required or not. Similar to the case above, in 6.7.3.8.136, it says "Actions on objects [that are volatile] shall not be ... reordered [across sequence points]." This has the same unfortunate linguistic ambiguity.

Comment: @Matt: The Standard makes no attempt to mandate everything needed to make an implementation suitable for any particular purpose.  The question of whether an implementation should be regarded as suitable for purposes that would require strong `volatile` semantics is thus outside the Standard's jurisdiction.  With the `volatile` issues as with most others, the Standard doesn't require that implementations behave usefully, but quality implementations designed for tasks requiring certain behaviors should support those behaviors without regard for whether the Standard would require that they do so.

Comment: @supercat: This is interesting.  I had assumed the standard was an attempt at something analogous to an API for how source code controls the computer (via compilation and then execution), defining a standardized meeting point that compiler writers and programmers could rely on.  For example, when programming embedded systems, I had assumed I can rely on "volatile" because of the standard, but your comment makes me think I am relying more on a historical understanding shared with the compiler writers, an understanding that the standard has not even tried to capture very clearly.

Comment: @Matt: An understanding which the authors of the Standard didn't think they should try to capture because people writing compilers for different purposes would be better placed than the Committee to judge how to best fit their needs.  Unfortunately, clang and gcc view any failure of the Standard to mandate something as a judgment by the Committee that it should be viewed as deprecated.

Answer (score 7):

I'm no expert, but cppreference.com has what appears to me to be some pretty good [information on `volatile`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/volatile). Here's the gist of it:

> Every access (both read and write) made through an lvalue expression
>   of volatile-qualified type is considered an observable side effect for
>   the purpose of optimization and is evaluated strictly according to the
>   rules of the abstract machine (that is, all writes are completed at
>   some time before the next sequence point). This means that within a
>   single thread of execution, a volatile access cannot be optimized out
>   or reordered relative to another visible side effect that is separated
>   by a sequence point from the volatile access.

It also gives some uses:

> Uses of volatile
>
> 1) static volatile objects model memory-mapped I/O ports, and static
>   const volatile objects model memory-mapped input ports, such as a
>   real-time clock
>
> 2) static volatile objects of type sig_atomic_t are used for
>   communication with signal handlers.
>
> 3) volatile variables that are local to a function that contains an
>   invocation of the setjmp macro are the only local variables guaranteed
>   to retain their values after longjmp returns.
>
> 4) In addition, volatile variables can be used to disable certain
>   forms of optimization, e.g. to disable dead store elimination or
>   constant folding for microbenchmarks.

And of course, it mentions that `volatile` is not useful for thread synchronization:

> Note that volatile variables are not suitable for communication
>   between threads; they do not offer atomicity, synchronization, or
>   memory ordering. A read from a volatile variable that is modified by
>   another thread without synchronization or concurrent modification from
>   two unsynchronized threads is undefined behavior due to a data race.

Comment: In particular, (2) and (3) are relevant to portable code.

Comment: @T.E.D. In spite of the domain name, the link is to information about C, not C++

Comment: @NateEldredge You can rarely use `longjmp` in C++ code.

Comment: @DavidBrown C and C++ have the same definition of an observable SE, and essentially the same thread primitives.

Answer (score 2):

The ISO C standard, no, but **in practice all machines that we run threads across have coherent shared memory**, so `volatile` in practice works somewhat like `_Atomic` with `memory_order_relaxed`, at least for pure-load / pure-store operations on small-enough types.  (But of course only `_Atomic` will give you [atomic RMWs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393850/can-num-be-atomic-for-int-num) for stuff like `n += 1;`)

There's also the question of what exactly `volatile` means to a compiler.  The standard allows wiggle room, but in real-world compilers, it means the load or store has to actually happen in the asm.  No more, no less.  (A compiler that didn't work this way couldn't correctly compile pre-C11 multi-threaded code that used hand-rolled volatile, so that de-facto standard is a requirement for compilers to be generally useful and for anyone to want to actually use them.  ISO C leaves enough choice up to the implementation that a DeathStation 9000 could be ISO C compliant and almost totally unusable for real programs, and break most real code bases.)

The requirement that `volatile` accesses are guaranteed to happen in source order is normally interpreted as putting the asm in that order, leaving runtime reordering at the mercy of the target machine's memory model.  `volatile` accesses aren't ordered wrt. anything else, so plain operations can still optimize away separately from them.

---

**[When to use volatile with multi threading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557979/when-to-use-volatile-with-multi-threading/58535118#58535118)** is a C++ version of the question.  Answer: basically never, use stdatomic.  My answer there explains why cache-coherency makes `volatile` useful in practice: there are no C or C++ implementations I'm aware of where `shared_var.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed)` needs to explicitly flush anything to make the store visible to other cores.  It compiles to just a normal asm store instruction, for variables narrow enough to be "naturally" atomic.

(Memory barriers just make this core wait, e.g. until the store commits from the store buffer to L1d cache and thus becomes globally visible, before doing later loads/stores.  So they order this core's accesses to coherent shared memory.)

For example, the Linux kernel depends on this, using `volatile` for inter-thread visibility, and `asm()` for memory barriers to order those accesses, and for atomic-RMW operations.  All multi-core systems that can run a single instance of Linux across those cores have coherent shared memory.

There are some rare systems with shared memory that isn't coherent, for example some clusters.  But you don't run threads of the same process across different coherency domains.  (Or run a single instance of the OS on it).  Instead, the shared memory has to get mapped differently from normal write-back cacheable, or you have to do explicit flushing.